# Having an issue with WWDR Appcelerator Titanium when building for device

Tags: ios, appcelerator

When publishing for device or for distribution in the Apple App Store, I'm getting the error: "[ERROR] :  Apple’s World Wide Developer Relations (WWDR) intermediate certificate is not installed."

However, the certificate is installed correctly. When building from XCode, it works fine.

Not sure how to rectify.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple WWDR Certificate has expired 02/14/2016. You will need to install new from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
But due to bug in one of titanium lib that can not work. If so you will need to make sure you add the certificate to your System keychain (not login or any other) or do this small patch on the Titanium SDK:

```
sed -i '' 's/results\.certs\.wwdr = tmp\.length && tmp\[0\]\.invalid === false;/results.certs.wwdr = results.certs.wwdr || (tmp.length \&\& tmp[0].invalid === false);/' /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/SDK_VERSION/node_modules/ioslib/lib/certs.js
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting this @farwayer! I've created a [JIRA ticket and PR](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20400) which should make it to 5.2.0. Until then an easier workaround is to add the certificate to your system keychain. Then Titanium should find it. I've also added this as a note to http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/experiencing-ios-certification-issues-check-your-wwdr-intermediate-certificate/#build

Comment: I actually read something about the conflicting certs between login and System keychains. I deleted the WWDR cert from the System keychain, restarted my comp, and the project built fine. Either way definitely an issue. Thanks for the resources everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I found the same problem when installing the certificate. I just read [Fokke Zandbergen's article](https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/experiencing-ios-certification-issues-check-your-wwdr-intermediate-certificate/) and now it's working.
Pay attention to the note:

> NOTE: Please make sure you select the System keychain as we have recently discovered an issue where the certificate might not be found in your login or other keychains.